# Xpath support in my browser?

Tags: browser, xpath

How can i find which version of xpath is being supported in my browser ?

There are currently ver 1 and 2. 2 is way advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the user agent and versions (minor/major) and compare with a given supported list inside your client-side JavaScript code.

E.g. you could implement [this list from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28XML%29#Query_technologies).

Answer (score 1):

I think the built-in XPath implementations in current desktop browsers like IE, Mozilla, Opera, Safari and Chrome are all XPath 1.0 implementations.
If you want XPath 2.0 client-side then your best bet is to look at attempts to implement XQuery 1.0 (of which XPath 2.0 is a subset) in the browser, like http://www.xqib.org/.

Answer (score 1):

**At present the five major browsers only implement XPath 1.0**.

If you want XPath 2.0 support you can either use **[Saxon CE](http://www.saxonica.com/download/downloadSaxonCE.xml)** (Saxon cross-compiled to Javascript that is working in all major browsers). or **[XQIB](http://www.xqib.org/)** (XQuery in the browser).